# NSCalendar ordinalityOfUnit doesn't return the day of the week correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

I have to determine the day of the week in an Objective C class.
Trying to use this method:

```
- (NSUInteger)ordinalityOfUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)smaller 
                        inUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)larger 
                       forDate:(NSDate *)date;
```

This is my code:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
(int) [gregorian ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday inUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday forDate:[NSDate date]];
```

It always returns -1, no matter what day it is. Even if I change the date, or loop through a whole week.
However, using this method, it works well:

```
- (NSDateComponents *)components:(NSCalendarUnit)unitFlags 
                        fromDate:(NSDate *)date;
```

So far so good. The only problem is: this method is deprecated (first deprecated in iOS 8.0, so quite a long time ago).
Little bit afraid of using old deprecated methods for production. Is there a way of making the (not even very) new method work?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1414841-components?language=objc I don't see it deprecated. What may be deprecated from iOS8 is `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` vs `NSCalendarUnitWeekday`.

Comment: Also, check the documentation of `ordinalityOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:`. It says to return `NSNotFound` in some cases (like `smaller` >= `larger`? and since in your case they are equal), `NSNotFound` that may be translated as `-1` from casting `NSUInteger` to `int`

Comment: Larme: You are right. Thank you! It was an easy fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `ordinalityOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:` docs:

> Returns, for a given absolute time, the ordinal number of a smaller calendar unit (such as a day) within a specified larger calendar unit (such as a week).

You have specified the *same* unit for the first two arguments, you need to specify day for the first and week for the second:

```
[gregorian ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth forDate:[NSDate date]]
```

HTH